# KVM Domain not creating

Tags: kvm, libvirt

While I am trying to create a new KVM Machine , I am getting the following error ,

```
Unable to complete install: 'Domain has not existed.  You should be able to find more information in the logs'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 44, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1910, in do_install
    guest.start_install(False, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1223, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1303, in _create_guest
    self._consolechild) = self._wait_and_connect_console(consolecb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1328, in _wait_and_connect_console
    raise RuntimeError(_("Domain has not existed.  You should be "
RuntimeError: Domain has not existed.  You should be able to find more information in the logs
```

**NOTE:**  I am getting this error while I am trying to use custom Storage pool that is , `/dev/sdaXX/` mounted on `/vmstore` mount point & image file path `/vmstore/disk.img`

ERROR_LOG

```
2014-03-24 21:06:48.178+0000: 7166: error : virNetSocketReadWire:1194 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error
2014-03-24 21:07:56.242+0000: 7170: warning : qemuSetupCgroupForVcpu:566 : Unable to get vcpus' pids.
2014-03-24 21:07:56.329+0000: 7166: error : qemuMonitorIO:614 : internal error End of file from monitor
2014-03-24 21:16:04.269+0000: 7167: warning : qemuSetupCgroupForVcpu:566 : Unable to get vcpus' pids.
2014-03-24 21:16:04.344+0000: 7166: error : qemuMonitorIO:614 : internal error End of file from monitor
2014-03-24 21:16:24.361+0000: 7167: warning : qemuSetupCgroupForVcpu:566 : Unable to get vcpus' pids.
2014-03-24 21:16:24.436+0000: 7166: error : qemuMonitorIO:614 : internal error End of file from monitor
```

Comment: Obvious followup question: It says you should be able to find more information in the logs. Have you checked to logs? Start with the ones in `/var/log/libvirt`

Comment: Its saying some monitor error issue

Comment: Try running _some fixing command_. Those generally work.

Comment: some fixing command ?

Comment: @rajagenupula I'm pretty sure Stephane was being sarcastic, as you'd left a comment about it being "some monitor error", which wasn't useful. Now you've edited the question and put in the details—good. Which log file did that come from? And are there any other log messages generated when you try to create the VM?

Comment: Thats all I got @derobert

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem - same error message.
I found out that the VM will continue creation, if I give it less than 4gb RAM,

1. so e.g. 3gb RAM VM started to install
2. the installation process was terribly slow
3. in `/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log`  I saw errors like:

   ```
   qemuSetupCgroupForVcpu:566 : Unable to get vcpus' pids
   ```
4. I did not have all kvm kernel modules loaded:

   ```
   kvm_intel              54285  0 
   kvm                   333172  1 kvm_intel
   ```

   I was missing the "kvm_intel" module from the list you can see above (the above is already correct output)
   and upon trying "modprobe kvm_intel" i was getting error
5. I rebooted machine, got to BIOS and finally fixed everything by having the "allow intel virtualization" switched to "on" (was off)

I wouldn't dream, that the BIOS had the virtualization support disabled, but ... it was the HP xw8400 workstation 5yrs old

btw during the creation I also had a problem with "permission denied" while trying to install the virtual machine to `*.img` (raw).
the message was something like:

```
"warning kvm is not available"
```

It was a SELinux problem, because I switched default VM storage pool to customized path (different FS)

```
$ ls -alZ /var/lib/libvirt/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:virt_image_t:s0 images

$ semanage fcontext -a -t virt_image_t "/data/VM_KVM/(/.*)?"

$ restorecon -R -v /data/VM_KVM/
```

fixed the SElinux problem.

Comment: Would you please read up on formatting in the Markdown dialect used here? I'll try to fix a few deficiencies, but you are the author and probably better suited.